# assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-strings, assignment-operator, strcat

I'm trying to keep concatenating the largeVal with smallVal when input a, and store the result into `arr[]` array.

```
int driver()
{
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char reply[MAXLINE * 1000];
    char largeVal[MAXLINE] =
        "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10";
    char smallVal[MAXLINE] = "5";

    while (strcmp(buffer,"a") == 0)
    {
        arr[MAXLINE * 1000] = strcat(smallVal, largeVal);
    }
    return foo(buffer, reply);
}
```

The error message is the following:

> warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

```
   91 |         arr[MAXLINE * 1000] = strcat(smallReply, largeReply);
      |                               ^
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean, "when input a"? `buffer` is uninitialized and nothing ever modifies it. There's no user input or anything.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is clear enough. In this assignment statement

```
arr[MAXLINE * 1000] = strcat(smallVal, largeVal);
```

the left operand has the type `char` while the right operand has the type `char *` (the return type of the function `strcat`). So the statement does not make a sense.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
strcpy( arr, strcat(smallVal, largeVal) );
```

Pay attention to that the array `smallVal` should be large enough to store the appended string from the array `largeVal`.

Also this while loop

```
while (strcmp(buffer,"a") == 0)
{
    arr[MAXLINE * 1000] = strcat(smallVal, largeVal);
}
```

in any case invokes undefined behavior because the local array `buffer` is uninitialized.

```
char buffer[MAXLINE];
```

And moreover even if the array `buffer` will be initialized by the string `"a"` the loop will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
arr[MAXLINE * 1000] = strcat(smallVal, largeVal);
```

there are two issues. First, you are not assigning the string to `arr`, but trying to access the element in position `[MAXLINE * 1000]`, which, in turn is just a plain `char`. Second, `strcat` returns an pointer to a `char` (array), i.e.: `char *`. So, you are trying to assign a pointer in a place that expects a value.